# FileNotFoundError: using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I ran an example, I get the following errors and don't know why.

```
# Import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd

# Import the cars.csv data: cars
cars = pd.read_csv('cars.csv')

# Print out cars
print(cars)
```

And when I run, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gaara_000/PycharmProjects/firstPj/index.py", line 2, in <module>
    cars = pd.read_csv('cars.csv')
  File "C:\Users\gaara_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\gaara_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 405, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\gaara_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 764, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\gaara_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 985, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\gaara_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1605, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 394, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:4209)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 710, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas\_libs\parsers.c:8873)
FileNotFoundError: File b'cars.csv' does not exist
```

I think this is correct code.

I got this code from https://www.learnpython.org/en/Pandas_Basics

Comment: `File b'cars.csv' does not exist` It's because there is no `cars.csv` in your directory

Comment: Last line: `FileNotFoundError: File b'cars.csv' does not exist` is your clue. Before you ask another question, search around for questions and answers with both the `python` and `path` tags, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+and+%5Bpath%5D) for example.

Comment: I don't know why, but its work correctly now. anw, thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

You have to save both your program and cars.csv in same folder if you are using this. `cars = pd.read_csv('cars.csv')` or you can give full path to your csv file like this `(r'C:\Users\Vikas Chauhan\Desktop\cars.csv')`.
Your code is correct.

```
import pandas as pd

cars = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Vikas Chauhan\Desktop\cars.csv')

# Print out cars
print(cars)
```

OutPut is

```
  vikas   test
0  vika  test2
```

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Python looks in your current working directory, not in the directory where the script is stored. Beginners get this confused all the time (partially also because they don't know how the two are different).

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have no `cars.csv` file. Open a text editor and create the following file in the **same directory** as your `.py` file.

cars.csv:

```
CarName,Price
Bmw,50000$
Audi,20000$
Ferrari,100000$
```

Now try running the code. And you'll get the output,

```
   CarName    Price
0      Bmw   50000$
1     Audi   20000$
2  Ferrari  100000$
```

So what `pd.read_csv()` does is reads a `csv` file  (default **delimiter** is `,` you can change that too)

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Python looks in your current working directory, not in the directory where the script is stored. Beginners get this confused all the time (partially also because they don't know how the two are different).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file is in the same Directory as your python code, Otherwise you need to give it a directory path. Hope that works!

Comment: No, that's incorrect. Python looks in your current working directory, not in the directory where the script is stored. Beginners get this confused all the time (partially also because they don't know how the two are different).

Answer (score -1):

dataset = pds.read_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"Data.csv"))

use getcwd to get current directory.

Comment: No, don't. `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'filename'))` is exactly equivalent to `'filename'` as far as `open()` etc is concerned.